# Is it possible to use the getboolarg function in interpreter.cpp

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, compiling, c++

I'm looking to use the GetBoolArg() function in the interpreter.cpp file what changes do I have to make for it to work?

I'm still new to development c, I tried several #include but without success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've tried `#include <common/args.h>` ?

Comment: @MichaelFolksonYes despite the fact that it is declared in this file it did not work.

Comment: You're recompiling after you've made the change?

Comment: @MichaelFolkson Yes, I get the following error: `error: use of undeclared identifier 'GetBoolArg'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`interpreter.cpp` is part of the internal `libbitcoin_consensus` library, while `GetBoolArg()` is in `common/args.{h/cpp}` which is part of the internal `libbitcoin_common` library. The `Makefile` specifies a linking order that has `libbitcoin_common` depend on `libbitcoin_consensus`. In order for implementation to work, you would have to modify the `Makefile` and shuffle things around so that `libbitcoin_consensus` could depend on `libbitcoin_common` without any circular dependencies.

However this is an indicator that your implementation probably has a layer violation. Things in `libbitcoin_consensus` should not need access to things in `libbitcoin_common`, Rather you should add or modify one of the data passing classes to hold the value for the parameter that you want passed, and that class will be filled by callers located somewhere that already depends on both `libbitcoin_common` and `libbitcoin_consensus`.

Comment: I see thank you for the answer, I will try to modify my code accordingly.